# How to Set c_cpp_properties.json include path for ORB SLAM3 in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I can build ORB SLAM3 and its ROS wrapper, however I can't find the header file in my vscode.

The include of `ros_stereo_inertial.cc` is like below, and I can't jump into the header file.

```
#include "../../../include/System.h"
#include "../include/ImuTypes.h"
```

Here is my `tree` information of `ORB SLAM3`

```
├── build
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── Thirdparty
├── build_ros.sh
├── build.sh
├── Calibration_Tutorial.pdf
├── Changelog.md
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Dependencies.md
├── evaluation
│   ├── associate.py
│   ├── evaluate_ate_scale.py
│   └── Ground_truth
├── Examples
│   ├── Calibration
│   ├── Monocular
│   ├── Monocular-Inertial
│   ├── REAMDME.md
│   ├── RGB-D
│   ├── RGB-D-Inertial
│   ├── ROS
│   ├── Stereo
│   └── Stereo-Inertial
├── Examples_old
│   ├── Monocular
│   ├── Monocular-Inertial
│   ├── REAMDME.md
│   ├── RGB-D
│   ├── RGB-D-Inertial
│   ├── ROS
│   ├── Stereo
│   └── Stereo-Inertial
├── include
│   ├── Atlas.h
│   ├── CameraModels
│   ├── Config.h
│   ├── Converter.h
│   ├── FrameDrawer.h
│   ├── Frame.h
│   ├── G2oTypes.h
│   ├── GeometricTools.h
│   ├── ImuTypes.h
│   ├── KeyFrameDatabase.h
│   ├── KeyFrame.h
│   ├── LocalMapping.h
│   ├── LoopClosing.h
│   ├── MapDrawer.h
│   ├── Map.h
│   ├── MapPoint.h
│   ├── MLPnPsolver.h
│   ├── OptimizableTypes.h
│   ├── Optimizer.h
│   ├── ORBextractor.h
│   ├── ORBmatcher.h
│   ├── ORBVocabulary.h
│   ├── SerializationUtils.h
│   ├── Settings.h
│   ├── Sim3Solver.h
│   ├── System.h
│   ├── Tracking.h
│   ├── TwoViewReconstruction.h
│   └── Viewer.h
├── lib
│   └── libORB_SLAM3.so
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── Atlas.cc
│   ├── CameraModels
│   ├── Config.cc
│   ├── Converter.cc
│   ├── Frame.cc
│   ├── FrameDrawer.cc
│   ├── G2oTypes.cc
│   ├── GeometricTools.cc
│   ├── ImuTypes.cc
│   ├── KeyFrame.cc
│   ├── KeyFrameDatabase.cc
│   ├── LocalMapping.cc
│   ├── LoopClosing.cc
│   ├── Map.cc
│   ├── MapDrawer.cc
│   ├── MapPoint.cc
│   ├── MLPnPsolver.cpp
│   ├── OptimizableTypes.cpp
│   ├── Optimizer.cc
│   ├── ORBextractor.cc
│   ├── ORBmatcher.cc
│   ├── Settings.cc
│   ├── Sim3Solver.cc
│   ├── System.cc
│   ├── Tracking.cc
│   ├── TwoViewReconstruction.cc
│   └── Viewer.cc
├── Thirdparty
│   ├── DBoW2
│   ├── g2o
│   └── Sophus
└── Vocabulary
    ├── ORBvoc.txt
    └── ORBvoc.txt.tar.gz
```

And the `tree` information of `ORB SLAM3` ROS Workspace

```
├── Asus.yaml
├── build
│   ├── atomic_configure
│   ├── bin
│   ├── catkin
│   ├── catkin_generated
│   ├── CATKIN_IGNORE
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── devel
│   ├── gtest
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── test_results
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── config
│   ├── oak-d.txt
│   └── oak-d.yaml
├── manifest.xml
├── Mono
├── MonoAR
├── Mono_Inertial
├── RGBD
├── src
│   ├── AR
│   ├── my_ros_stereo_inertial.cc
│   ├── ros_mono.cc
│   ├── ros_mono_inertial.cc
│   ├── ros_rgbd.cc
│   ├── ros_stereo.cc
│   └── ros_stereo_inertial.cc
├── start_orbslam.sh
├── Stereo
└── Stereo_Inertial
```

Here is my current include Path

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "browse": {
                "databaseFilename": "${default}",
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
            },
            "includePath": [
                "/opt/ros/noetic/include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/**",
                "/home/yx/Downloads/ORB_SLAM3/ThirdParty",
                "/home/yx/Downloads/ORB_SLAM3/include"
            ],
            "name": "ROS",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```